# Postgres Streaming Replication getting stuck at 30% data

Tags: database, postgresql, replication

I am trying to set up streaming replication between a PostgreSQL primary server with 3 TB of data and a standby server. However, I am encountering a problem where replication always stops at around 30% of data replication (approximately 900 GBs of data). Previously, when attempting replication with only 1 TB of data, the process stopped at around 300 GBs of data. I need help resolving this issue and avoiding the replication limit.

Despite the efforts, the replication process still halts at approximately 30% of data replication. I suspect there might be a limitation or bottleneck in the PostgreSQL configuration that I am not aware of.

Could someone please provide guidance on how to avoid this replication limit and successfully replicate the entire 3 TB dataset to the standby server?

Any assistance or insights into this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

I have attempted to set up streaming replication between a PostgreSQL primary server with 3 TB of data and a standby server. I followed the official PostgreSQL documentation for configuring replication and made sure the postgresql.conf and pg_hba.conf files were correctly configured. I also ensured that both servers were running the same PostgreSQL version

To troubleshoot the issue, I checked the PostgreSQL logs on both servers for any error messages or warnings related to replication, but I did not find any specific errors.

I attempted to increase the replication slot size to allow for larger amounts of data, but it did not resolve the problem. I even tried using logical replication instead of streaming replication, but the replication still stalled at around 30% completion.

I expected the replication process to complete successfully and replicate the entire 3 TB dataset from the primary to the standby server. However, it consistently stops at around 30% of data replication (approximately 900 GBs of data)."

Comment: Could you please share the exact steps that you did?

Comment: Are you talking about `pg_basebackup` that stops transferring data? If you start replication, the whole database must already have been transferred. Or are you talking about ogical replication?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe yes I am talking about pg_basebackup. I want to transfer the  3TB of data to the standby server and because the primary server is being constantly filled with data I want that streaming to continue. Is streaming replication not a valid method for it?

Comment: Yes, sure, streaming replication is good for replication. Without more details, we cannot guess what's going on.

Comment: I'm not too sure however is this a https://serverfault.com/ type question?

Comment: Use system tools, like `top` and `vmstat` and `strace` (on linux) to see what is going on.